# PHP to run jquery script every 'x' minutes

Tags: php, jquery

I've been looking through multiple questions but I didn't understand much (it figures since all I know in PHP are contact forms and basic stuff) from what seemed to be similar questions.

I only need a php script to run on the server side and run a jquery script every 'x' minutes...in jquery I could simply set an interval and that would be it but it will not run if the page isn't accessed and I want it to run continuously.

If you would please have the patience to give an example and maybe explain the principle a little...Thanks

Comment: Look into running a cron job on your server.

Comment: I would like to know what you are trying to achieve before answering this question.

Comment: we need some extra info: you have a webpage that has a jquery script inside it that you want to run as if the page were accessed by a browser? or do you have some server side jquery script?

Comment: @maartenVenema I am just creating a jquery script that tests if the website is online by checking if a called image loads. I want to perform that test every hour or so. That's what I want to use it for.

Comment: hi please try the setInterval() method in Jquery, You can use this method to run after a certain interval

Comment: @alexalex jquery se afla in interiorul unei pagini separate. Mersi

Comment: @Alin Ok so why not do it all serverside and use the interval methods of Javascript?

Comment: @robin Sorry to say but setInterval() will not work until the page is accessed!

Comment: you can test the online-status of a website without jQuery. You can set up a cronjob with runs a php-script every hour. Have a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-website-is-available/)

Comment: why dont you write a code to refresh the php page after every hour

Comment: @empiric, that looks promising, I'll go by and read it and see where it takes me :)

Comment: @empiric Well thanks, I tested one of the scripts and it's working nice ^^ I see it's a felony here to not know something and ask for guidance...have a great day !

Comment: use cron for this ;)

Comment: after getting info about how things work in comments you can update your question to reflect what you need so you won't attract negative score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What needs to be achieved is to verify if a website/webpage is up.

There is no point to run a cron job that will run a wget that will run a php script! If you can run a cron job I'll assume you are on a unix server and can use a bash script (win-bash will probably run on windows too but I'm not familiar with that)

There is a nice thread on serverfault.com that is looking for almost the same thing: [script to automatically test if a web site is available](https://serverfault.com/questions/282215/script-to-automatically-test-if-a-web-site-is-available).

and one script that you can easily customize to do what you want is this one:

```
#! /usr/bin/sh

function check {
 if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
     echo "Error occurred getting URL $1:"
     if [ $? -eq 6 ]; then
         echo "Unable to resolve host"
     fi
     if [$? -eq 7 ]; then
         echo "Unable to connect to host"
     fi
     exit 1
 fi

}
curl -s -o "/dev/null" $1
check;
```

script and extra info from http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/276934.html user: wengland-ga

> In a nutshell, call the script with the HTTP URL to check.  curl will
>   silently try to get the file and send it to /dev/null.  If it fails,
>   it'll set the exit code, which is checked in the 'check' function.
>
> You may have to play with the curl parameters to make it work just how
>   you want it.  You can also redirect the curl output to a temp file,
>   and use grep and filesize checks to make sure the content is correct. 
>   Read the man page for details.
>
> Search Strategy:
>
> man curl
>   ://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=man+curl&btnG=Google+Search
>
> bash check exit code
>   ://www.google.com/search?q=bash+check+exit+code&sa=Google+Search
>
> bash +if syntax
>   ://www.google.com/search?q=bash+%2Bif+syntax&hl=en&lr=&ie=UTF-8&start=10&sa=N

It's a little bit of reading but this is the way I do it (I feel it's as no overkill as it gets)

On some servers curl might not be installed so you'll have to install it

Comment: Well thanks, I'll get into it right away, there's a lot of reading for me to do if I want to understand all of this properly. +1

Answer (score 1):

In according to your comment, that you want to check wether a website is online or not here a little example:

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout","05");//see 1)
set_time_limit(5); //see 1)

$f=fopen("http://www.example.com","r"); //see 2)

$r=fread($f,1000); //see 3)
fclose($f); // see 4)

if(strlen($r)>1) { //see 5)
    echo "<span class='online'>Online</span>";
}
else {
    echo "<span class='offline'>Offline</span>";
}
```

**Notes**

1) set stream-timeout to 5 seconds. If a site is offline the response should be send directly so there is no need to check over a long time

2) opens the url (only-read)

3) reads the first 1000 charaktars of the opend url (binary)

4) close the connection

5) check if data could be readed. If there is data existing the website could be opened

To install a cronjob which executes the php-script you can use:

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O /var/log/website_check.log http://www.webiste.com/pathTo/check.php
```

This will execute your php-script every our via `wget` and write the output into a log-file.
Please check the path for the cron, they can be different on your server. The url to the php-script can be changed to a absolute path, too. (e.g. `var/www/webroot/check.php`)

Comment: Hey, thanks, will certainly test it. Also thanks for not being a cocky know-it-all with those who simply have almost no knowledge of back-end programming. Giving you a +1 and if this works I will also accept the answer. :)